# Bind Select inside of table row from array not binding on activate

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In Aurelia (latest beta version), has anyone tried binding a select element inside of a table where the rows are bound to an array? I don't think it works on the initial load (activate() event).

Here's the example code:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr repeat.for="item of variations">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value.bind="item.name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" value.bind="item.controlId">
                <option>Select...</option>
                <option value="1">DropdownList</option>
                <option value="2">RadioList</option>
                <option value="3">Checkboxes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the viewmodel, the list of variations is built something like this in the activate() event:

```js
this.variations.forEach(v => {
        let variation = new Variation();

        variation.value = v.value;
        variation.text = v.text;
        variation.control = v.displayType;

        self.variations.push(variation);
});
```

The rest of the properties, ie. text input, show up fine on load. And the same view has regular selects outside of this table and they all bind correctly on load (ie. show the proper select option based on the value that is set programatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `item.controlId` a number? If so, what's probably happening is the number value is being compared using `===` with the string values of the option elements.  You'll need to make sure the option values are numbers:

Instead of `<option value="1">` use `<option model.bind="1">`

Comment: yup that did it, I actually just did a `.toString()` on the value coming from the server